# \cmidrule with two multirows not behaving correctly?

Tags: tables, booktabs

Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{b} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{QCDH} & Single & \multirow{2}{*}{$\frac{\pi_{q1}}{\pi_{s1}}$} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4} \\
 & $\pi_{q1}$ & $\pi_{q1}$ & $\pi_{s1}$ & \\
\midrule \\
0.1 & 0.0055 & 0.0018 & 0.0018 & 3.0555\\
0.5 & 0.1218 & 0.0830 & 0.0074 & 16.4594\\
2.5 & 0.7325 & 0.6771 & 0.3561 & 2.0570\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Pickup rates from QCDH and single SNP approach}
\end{table}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the first \cmidrule seems to take too much space.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but simply don't use `multirow`. The idea is nice, but completely unnecessary. Just leave your `b` and `\frac{\pi}{\pi}` in the top row, maybe just smash the bottom of the fraction as in `\smash[b]{$\frac{\pi_{q1}}{\pi_{s1}}$`. You'll realize that the output is nicely looking, decent and completely comprehesive :)

Comment: Btw, you speak about "first `\cmidrule`", but your example contains only one `\cmidrule`. However, if you want to remove the extra line, just remove the ```\\``` after your `\cmidrule`

Comment: This works. I am also trying to get some space between 2-3 and 4, I have tried this: ` \cmidrule{2-3}\morecmidrules\cmidrule{4}
`, but it will not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For having some space between two `\cmidrule`s at the same level, you never want `\morecmidrules`. Just use the `()` optional argument to shorten the line, as in the following:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}\toprule
  $b$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{QCDH} & Single & \smash[b]{$\frac{\pi_{q1}}{\pi_{s1}}$} \\
  \cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5} % notice there's no \\ here
  & $\pi_{q1}$ & $\pi_{q1}$ & $\pi_{s1}$ & \\
  \midrule[\heavyrulewidth] % notice there's no \\ here
0.1 & 0.0055 & 0.0018 & 0.0018 & 3.0555\\ \midrule
0.5 & 0.1218 & 0.0830 & 0.0074 & 16.4594\\ \midrule
2.5 & 0.7325 & 0.6771 & 0.3561 & 2.0570\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Pickup rates from QCDH and single SNP approach}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Very nice. I used `\cmidrule(l){4-4}`. But there is still no space between those two cmidrules.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo, everything is perfect now.

Answer (score 6):

Integrating the functionality of the `multirow` package with that of the `booktabs` package is tricky:  `\midrule` and `\cmidrule` add extra vertical spacing, but this extra spacing isn't taken into account when a `\multirow` instruction is executed. Thus, lining up the material in a 2-row multirow that also features `\midrule` or `\cmidrule` between those two rows is rarely satisfactory.

Moreover, I'd say your table neither requires nor benefits from applying a `\multirow` to the contents of columns 1 and 5 of the header. Just place those items in the very first row, and make the `\cmidrule` span just columns 2 and 3.

I think it's in general a good idea to *center* the items in the header even if the material in the body of the table isn't (or shouldn't be) centered. Finally, since the data are numeric, it's probably also a good idea to align them on their decimal points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.1]
           *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}
                S[table-format=2.4]}
\toprule
    {b} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{QCDH} & {Single} & {$\dfrac{\pi_{q1}}{\pi_{s1}}$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}  
 & {$\pi_{q1}$} & {$\pi_{q1}$} & {$\pi_{s1}$}  \\
\midrule 
0.1 & 0.0055 & 0.0018 & 0.0018 &  3.0555\\
0.5 & 0.1218 & 0.0830 & 0.0074 & 16.4594\\
2.5 & 0.7325 & 0.6771 & 0.3561 &  2.0570\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Pickup rates from QCDH and single SNP approach}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```